# Kafka/Connect/Streams for DB field update

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

my problem is the following:

I have 2 kafka topics:

- `customer-purchase`: contains information about a purchase made by a customer, with a field indicating the status being equal to `NEW`.
- `purchase-status`: containing events updating the latest status of the purchase, e.g. `IN TRANSIT`, `DELIVERED`...

Using kafka, kafka connect and/or kafka streams, I would like to end up with an SQL database which contains the purchase enriched with the latest status information.

In a DB world this would result in a simple `UPDATE` query.

Theoretically, I could write 1 consumer (or 1 connect sink) for the `customer-purchase`, where everything is simply dumped to the DB and 1 consumer for the `purchase-status` which would trigger a DB `UPDATE` query, but I was wondering whether there is a more kafka-like way to do this.

Note: using kafka-streams and joining the 2 topics there seemed a little overkill to me since I actually don't need the join but a simple update of a field. But I might be completely wrong in this assumption!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Theoretically, I could write 1 consumer (or 1 connect sink) for the customer-purchase, where everything is simply dumped to the DB and 1 consumer for the purchase-status which would trigger a DB UPDATE query, but I was wondering whether there is a more kafka-like way to do this.

This is pretty much what a table-table join in Kafka Streams actually does.

In your example you are looking at it through the lens of "one-event-at-a-time processing". Table-table joins send such "updates" very similarly to what you have described.  See the join semantics at https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#ktable-ktable-join.

> Note: using kafka-streams and joining the 2 topics there seemed a little overkill to me since I actually don't need the join but a simple update of a field. But I might be completely wrong in this assumption!

You mentioned you considered joining the two topics but decided against it. Why so? This seems like a good idea and also idiomatic to me. It is also not that much different from the DB world example: how would you do the enrich step in "SQL database which contains the purchase enriched with the latest status information"? This would effectively be a join operation (see above).

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your answer! Indeed I believe you are right in saying I would achieve exactly what I expect with a table-table join using Streams. My concern was that by doing so, if I understand correctly, I would effectively duplicate my database, as the information would live on both kafka and in the SQL db. At this point I could technically even drop the sql db altogether, but from a business perspective that's not possible, therefore I was looking for a way to end up with the updated db but without duplicating all the data into kafka as well.

Comment: Yes, you are right that data would then be present twice, once in the original DB and once in Kafka.